# Unable to open 'defaultSettings.json': Invalid regular expression: /*.xml/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting this error when trying to open the settings.json files or access preferences in VSCode.  The preferences pages are blank.  I have examined the settings.json file by opening it from the regular Windows File Explorer and don't see anything obviously amiss with it. I didn't see anything on the web in other questions about it. I tried deleting the settings.json file and it reset it, but I don't think that fixed it and I lose all my settings.  I tried adding them back in a few at a time, to track down a setting that might be causing it and updated the recommendations, but still getting the error.  I'm not sure where the "defaultSettings.json" file is.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  Also, I noticed that I am not able to authorize some of the OAuth logins, but I'm not sure if that is a separate issue.  When the browser redirects after logging in it displays a can't access page in the browser and doesn't respond in vscode.  I'm not sure if there is a setting that is missing or what is causing it.  I'm also using WSL2 and Docker containers.

Thanks!

Version: 1.59.0 (system setup)
Commit: 379476f0e13988d90fab105c5c19e7abc8b1dea8
Date: 2021-08-04T23:13:12.822Z
Electron: 13.1.7
Chrome: 91.0.4472.124
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.36-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000

Comment: do you use the desktop VSC or Browser VSC? Who is complaining: VSC or some extension?

Comment: desktop.  I just uninstalled reinstalled it and set up my packages again and it seems to work now.  I think there were some old settings that were messing with it or something.  It was weird. I'm not sure what it was.

Answer (score 1):

Installed the VSCode insider edition and installed all my packages there and things seem to work with that version. Unless someone has a better idea I'll just mark this closed.  I'll just use that the insider edition for now and keep the other one as a backup.